# Translation of 0-dimensional objects

Tags: geometry, vectors

As far as I can understand we can think of any line on a plane as a product of translation of some other arbitrary line by some arbitrary vector (and vice versa). But while it makes sense when we talk about lines, I cannot imagine the same procedure for dots. Is it even "possible" to translate a dot such that its origin and a translated "copy" would define a line?

Comment: When you talk about "points", "vectors" and "translating point by some arbitrary vector", it means you are dealing with some [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space); I would suggest you take a look at this wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Any* point is a translate of *any* other point:
$$y = x + (y - x).$$

Taking any two points $x_0\ne y_0$ of a line, the line can be written as the set
$$\{x_0 + t(y_0 - x_0)\,\vert\,t\in\Bbb R\}.$$